# convert std::string to jstring encoded using windows-1256

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, stdstring

I am using a library (libcurl) that requests a certain webpage with some Arabic content. when I obtain the string response it has Arabic characters and the whole response is encoded in WINDOWS-1256.

the problem is arabic chars dont show up properly.

is there a way to convert an std::string to a jstring encoded in WINDOWS-1256?

by the way I tried `env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());` and the application crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java strings use UTF-16.  JNI has no concept of charset encodings other than UTF-8 and UTF-16 (unless you use JNI calls to access Java's [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class directly, but Java only implements a small subset of charsets, and `Windows-1256` is not one of them unless the underlying Java JVM specifically implements it).

JNI's `NewStringUTF()` function requires UTF-8 input (and not just standard UTF-8 but Java's special [**modified UTF-8**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8)) and returns a UTF-16 encoded `JString`.

So you would have to first convert the original Arabic data from Windows-1256 to (modified) UTF-8 before then calling `NewStringUTF()`.  A better option would be to convert the data to UTF-16 directly and then use JNI's `NewString()` function.  But either way, you can use [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), [ICU4JNI](http://userguide.icu-project.org/usefrom/jni), or any other Unicode library of your choosing for the actual conversion itself one way or the other.